# pasar una consulta sql a codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

La consulta SQL es asi: 
SELECT grupo, aula_lunes, inicio_lunes, fin_lunes, aula_martes, inicio_martes, fin_martes, aula_miercoles, inicio_miercoles, fin_miercoles, aula_jueves, inicio_jueves, fin_jueves, aula_viernes, inicio_viernes, fin_viernes, 
COUNT(* ) as TOTAL FROM excel_script u 
WHERE grupo LIKE 't%' 
GROUP BY grupo, aula_lunes, inicio_lunes, fin_lunes, aula_martes, inicio_martes, fin_martes, aula_miercoles, inicio_miercoles, fin_miercoles, aula_jueves, inicio_jueves, fin_jueves, aula_viernes, inicio_viernes, fin_viernes 
 HAVING COUNT(*)>1

En CodeIgniter tengo algo asi:

$db = \Config\Database::connect();

```
            $builder = $db->table('excel_script');
            $builder->select("
                excel_script.grupo,
                excel_script.aula_lunes, 
                excel_script.inicio_lunes, 
                excel_script.fin_lunes, 
                excel_script.aula_martes, 
                excel_script.inicio_martes, 
                excel_script.fin_martes, 
                excel_script.aula_miercoles, 
                excel_script.inicio_miercoles, 
                excel_script.fin_miercoles, 
                excel_script.aula_jueves, 
                excel_script.inicio_jueves, 
                excel_script.fin_jueves, 
                excel_script.aula_viernes, 
                excel_script.inicio_viernes, 
                excel_script.fin_viernes,
                COUNT(*) as TOTAL
            ");
            $builder->like("excel_script.grupo","t","after");
            /*
            $builder->group_by(
                "excel_script.grupo", 
                "excel_script.aula_lunes", 
                "excel_script.inicio_lunes", 
                "excel_script.fin_lunes", 
                "excel_script.aula_martes", 
                "excel_script.inicio_martes", 
                "excel_script.fin_martes", 
                "excel_script.aula_miercoles", 
                "excel_script.inicio_miercoles", 
                "excel_script.fin_miercoles", 
                "excel_script.aula_jueves", 
                "excel_script.inicio_jueves", 
                "excel_script.fin_jueves", 
                "excel_script.aula_viernes", 
                "excel_script.inicio_viernes", 
                "excel_script.fin_viernes"
                )
            );
            
            $builder->having('TOTAL > 1', null, false);
            
            $query = $builder->get();
            $results = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.